# Error converting data type varchar to numeric. Insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting this error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

and I think the problem is with the dropdown lists because for example when the user select the name is saving the id. That is my code and I am attaching a screenshot as well

[Screenshot after I run the code in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvVEO.jpg)

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
    {
        TextBox txtActivity = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtActivity");
        TextBox ftxtDate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtDate");
        TextBox ftxtQno = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtQno");
        DropDownList fddlCName = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("fddlCName") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList fddlMmodel = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("fddlMmodel") as DropDownList;
        TextBox ftxtQuantity = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtQuantity");
        TextBox ftxtvalueGBR = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtvalueGBR");
        TextBox ftxtvalueEUR = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtvalueEUR");
        TextBox ftxtRate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtRate");
        TextBox ftxtweightedValue = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtweightedValue");
        DropDownList fddlStatus = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("fddlStatus") as DropDownList;
        TextBox ftxtestDecisionDate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtestDecisionDate");
        TextBox ftxtPromisedDeliveryDate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtPromisedDeliveryDate");

        con.Open();          
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SalesActivity(Activity_ID, Date, Quatation_Number, Customer_ID, Product_ID, Quantity, valueGBR, valueEUR, Rate, weightedValue, Status_ID, estDecisionDate, PromisedDeliveryDate) values('" + txtActivity.Text + "','" + ftxtDate.Text + "','" + ftxtQno.Text + "','" + fddlCName.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + fddlMmodel.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + ftxtQuantity.Text + "','" + ftxtvalueGBR.Text + "','" + ftxtvalueEUR.Text + "','" + ftxtweightedValue.Text + "','" + ftxtRate.Text + "','" + fddlStatus.SelectedItem.Value +  "','" + ftxtestDecisionDate.Text + "','" + ftxtPromisedDeliveryDate.Text + "')", con);

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        if (result == 1)
        {
            userSales();
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + txtActivity.Text + "'+'Sale Details inserted successfully');</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + txtActivity.Text + "'+' Sale Details not inserted');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: After you've dynamically created the SQL statement, capture it in your debugger.  Try executing the captured query directly.  I'm sure you'll see that you've misaligned the values you're attempting to insert, or perhaps have quotes around something that doesn't need it.

Comment: use [SqlCommandParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: if the database value is numeric (int, etc.) Getting the value of the dropdown is NOT Enough. You have to convert explicitly using C# convert function e.g.: "Conver.ToInt32(...value)

Comment: @DaniDev where i need to use that in the insert statemnt ? my id from the dropdown  list  is varchar

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado hi i tried with sqlcommand parameters but is not working again

Comment: I provided a answer which will address both the issues (if implemented correctly). You will need to follow the example for each of your parameters and convert to Int 32 as necessary

Comment: @jorenceto then it means you are either wrong in setting the parameter name or you are not setting the correct data type in your sqlcommand parameters.

Comment: Strings need to convert to numeric data type

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance to make sure your other questions are easier to read and have chance to be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 5):

This answer will address 2 issues

1. Protecting from SQL injection using Parameterized Queries
2. Converting to numeric values when required

1+2.  (Please note that for expedience I did not code for all your parameters )

In your Code Behind:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.CommandText =  "INSERT INTO SalesActivity(Activity_ID, Date, Quatation_Number, Customer_ID, Product_ID, Quantity, valueGBR, valueEUR, Rate, weightedValue, Status_ID, estDecisionDate, PromisedDeliveryDate) values(@Activity,@Date, @param3 ,@param4,@param5,@param6,@param7,@param8,etc................... )";                }
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", Convert.ToInt32(txtActivity.Text));
}
```

....Do this for all your parameters (convert to Int32 as required)

Comment: I would recommend along with this answer that that OP learn how to stored procedures to eliminate any potential SQL Injection and cleaner code / readability

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @DaniDev answers, if you are not sure content is a valid int then  safer option is

```
int val = 0;
Int32.TryParse( TextBox1.Text, out val );
```

This will provide you with some default value you can use. Int32.TryParse also returns a boolean value indicating whether it was able to parse or not, so you can even use it as the condition of an if statement.

See *[Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)* for more detailed information.